# html2canvas and jsPDF partial gray section

Tags: image, background, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to create a PDF from HTML using `html2canvas` and `jsPDF`. 
First I get all the html elements I want to pass to PDF as `image` and then I add them one by one as follows:

```
   var quality = 1
   var report1 = null
   var report2 = null
   var report3 = null
   var report4 = null
   var report5 = null
   var header = null

   html2canvas(document.querySelector('header'), {scale: quality})
        .then(canvas => {
            header = canvas
            html2canvas(document.querySelector('#report-1'), {scale: quality})
            .then(canvas => {
                report1 = canvas
                html2canvas(document.querySelector('#report-2'), {scale: quality})
                .then(canvas => {
                    report2 = canvas
                    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#report-3'), {scale: quality})
                        .then(canvas => {
                            report3 = canvas
                            html2canvas(document.querySelector('#report-4'), {scale: quality})
                                .then(canvas => {
                                    report4 = canvas
                                    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#report-5'), {scale: quality})
                                        .then(canvas => {
                                            report5 = canvas


                                            var imgDataHeader = header.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            var imgWidth = 210; 
                                            var imgHeight = header.height * imgWidth / header.width;
                                            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'A4');
                                            var position = 0
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataHeader, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 15;


                                            var imgDataReport1 = report1.toDataURL('image/png')
                                            imgHeight = report1.height * imgWidth / report1.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataReport1, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 5;

                                            var imgDataReport2 = report2.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = report2.height * imgWidth / report2.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataReport2, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 5;



                                            doc.addPage();
                                            position = 0


                                            imgDataHeader = header.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = header.height * imgWidth / header.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataHeader, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 15;

                                            var imgDataReport3 = report3.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = report3.height * imgWidth / report3.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataReport3, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 5;


                                            var imgDataReport4 = report4.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = report4.height * imgWidth / report4.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataReport4, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 5;


                                            doc.addPage();
                                            position = 0

                                            imgDataHeader = header.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = header.height * imgWidth / header.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataHeader, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 15;

                                            var imgDataReport5 = report5.toDataURL('image/png');
                                            imgHeight = report5.height * imgWidth / report5.width;
                                            doc.addImage(imgDataReport5, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                                            position += imgHeight + 5;


                                            doc.save( 'file-.pdf');
                                        })
                                })
                        })
                    })
             })
        })
```

The problem is that except the first clean area, the rest of elements (theoretically with a white background) appears with gray background.

**scale == 1**

[image]

If I increase the `scale html2canvas option` this problem disappears but charts borders turns totally white (they are inside a material card container which must appears too).

**scale == 2**

[image]

I tried changing other options available in html2canvas [options](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/) but nothing changes.

**Desired result**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem after I realized that the gray background color is in the `body`. Seems that `html2canvas` doesn't get the parent's style. So, I had to add `style="background:#f5f5f5f5"`in each `div`, `scale = 2` and adding the same background in the pdf page using the gray level `setFillColor` option:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'A4');
doc.setFillColor(245);
doc.rect(0, 0, 210, 700, "F");
```

Maybe this is a workaround but it's sufficient solution for me.

Answer (score 5):

For someone really struggling as you cannot find any answer, then try to put 'scale:2' in the configuration. This simple keyword solved everything about showing gray background.

Answer (score 2):

I Had The Same Problem For This Gray Background, And Here Is A Solution That Can Help you :
Make Your Chart Inside A Table with the id like this :

```
<table id="report-1">
     <tr>
       <td>
        <!-- Your Chart Here -->
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Every Chart Should Be Encompassed By Table